# How can i run a function based off of woocommerce_form_field() selection?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, sku

I am populating a dropdown from a `woocommerce_form_field()` as shown below:

```
// Add additional items to array 
$options = array( 
    0 => __( 'Select an option...', 'woocommerce' ),
    1 => __( 'No Compressor & Bracket ', 'woocommerce') 
    ) + $options;
    
// Add select field
woocommerce_form_field( 'compressor-options', array(
    'type'          => 'select',
    'label'         => __( 'Add Compressor & Bracket', $domain ),
    'required'      => false,
    'options'       => $options,
),'' );
echo '<p>Number of Compressor & Bracket options: ' . count( $options ) . '</p>';
```

I would like to change the SKU of the main product depending on the selection made by the user. I am currently unaware of how to do so.

I have a function to change the SKU, but it does not take in if the user makes a selection.

```
function change_current_sku() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! isset( $POST['compressor-options'] ) ) {

        echo '<div><br></div>';
        echo $product->get_sku() . ' (EX)';

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'change_current_sku' );
```

Is there a way to have an `onchange()` on the woocommerce_form_field?

Comment: You will need jQuery, Ajax or both to do that... Not PHP

Comment: `$POST['compressor-options']` will likely never be set. It's `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

Comment: @HowardE how could I go about that?

Comment: It sounds like you might have to do some more work on your end, and come up with a jQuery/Ajax script. You might start by looking at `focusout` and using that jQuery event to fire an ajax script to update the user_meta

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to simple type products only, then ajax per se is not necessary and just jQuery will do. So it depends on your specific requirements.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Some random options
    $random_options = array( 2 => 'abc', 3 => 'def', 4 => '(ghi)', 5 => 'jkl' );
   
    // Add additional items to array 
    $options = array( 
        0 => __( 'Select an option...', 'woocommerce' ),
        1 => __( 'No Compressor & Bracket ', 'woocommerce') 
    ) + $random_options;
        
    // Add select field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'compressor-options', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'label'         => __( 'Add Compressor & Bracket', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'      => false,
        'options'       => $options,
    ),'' );
    echo '<p>Number of Compressor & Bracket options: ' . count( $options ) . '</p>';

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($) {
        // On change
        $( document ).on( 'change', '#compressor-options', function () {
            var suffix = $( 'option:selected', this ).text();

            // Append
            $( '.my-product-sku .sku-suffix' ).text( suffix );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );

function action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    
    // Is a WC product
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        echo '<p class="my-product-sku">' . $product->get_sku() . ': ' . '<span class="sku-suffix"></p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 10 );
```